# Как выполнить в Android приложении консольную команду?

Tags: android, консоль, shell

Необходимо из приложения Android выполнить консольную команду как можно это сделать?

Comment: а в андроиде есть консоль?

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman да, он вообще на ядре linux и поддерживает команды linux (не все)

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, я очень удивился, когда узнал, что программы, написанные на Pascal (в программе Pascal GUI) и собранные под Android, умеют исполнять команды Android'a. Аналогично с обычным Android'ом (как в ответе). Можно даже попробовать написать аналог GParted, который будет уметь записывать образы дисков. Полезно, когда нет кардридера, а на карту нужно записать, например, образ какого-нибудь Linux'a для запуска на Orange Pi.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Так же, как и в обычном Java-приложении:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

Вот [функция](https://www.learn2crack.com/2014/03/android-executing-shell-commands.html), которая принимает команду, выполняет её и возвращает ответ:

```
public String Executer(String command) {

    StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();

    Process p;
    try {
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        p.waitFor();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

        String line = "";
        while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
            output.append(line + "n");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String response = output.toString();
    return response;

}
```